# If $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}$ does not exist, with $\{h_m\}\to 0$, why can we conclude $f$ not differentiable at $a$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

If we have a function $f(x)$ and we prove that at a point $a$ the limit

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}$$ does not exist, where $\{h_m\}$ is a sequence that converges to $0$, why can we conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $a$?

In other words, why can we conclude something about the differentiability of a function at a point $a$ based on the limit of a sequence?

I think it is related to the following theorem

**Spivak, *Calculus*, Ch. 22, Theorem 1** Let $f$ be a function defined in an open interval containing $c$ except perhaps at $c$. Then

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)=l$$
>
> $$\iff$$
>
> for every sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that
>
> 1. each $a_n$ is in the domain of $f$
> 2. each $a_n\neq c$
> 3. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=c$
>
> the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ satisfies
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=l$$

Let $\{a_n\}=\{a+h_m\}$ be any sequence with $\{h_m\}$ converging to $0$. Then

1. $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$
2. $a_n\neq a$
3. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$

Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Then, $g(a_n)=\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}$ is a sequence

but we showed previously that it doesn't converge, ie

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(a_n)$$

does not exist.

This seems to mean that the consequent of the theorem above is false. Hence the antecedent is false. And that means that the limit

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

does not exist, and therefore, $f$ is not differentiable at $a$.

Is this the underlying justification for our conclusion about differentiability of the function $f$ at $a$ based on a limit of a sequence?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. Differentiability is defined as :the $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists." Existence of the limit is equivalent to "$\lim_{n \to \infty} g(a_n)$ exists for every $a_n$ satisfying 1, 2, 3." If you find a sequence for which that limit doesn't exist, then you have shown the original limit does not exist, and thus the function is not differentiable.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}F(x)=L$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F(a_n)=L$ for any sequence $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$

Comment: @OliverDíaz Are there no additional assumptions? What about the function $F(x)=0$ for $x=1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $F(x)=1$ otherwise. Do we not have $a_n=1/n$ that converges to $0$, and $F(a_n)$ converging to 0 as well? But $F(x)$ does not have a defined limit at $0$.

Comment: @evianpring: notice that I said "for any sequence", not "some sequence".

Comment: I find the use of "any" very confusing. In my opinion, it is much clearer to use the term "every".

Comment: @evianpring: To me, "for any"="for all". I forgot to mention that the sequence $a_n$ should be such that $a_n\neq a$. See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793116/121671)

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine, but too lengthy.

Suppose $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=l$ exists for $g$ defined in a punctured neighborhood $U$ of $0$. Then, for every sequence $(h_m)$ in $U\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\lim_{m\to\infty}h_m=0$, it holds that $\lim_{m\to\infty}g(h_m)=l$.

This is a small part of the big theorem you quote and the easier one. Indeed, choose $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|h|<\delta$, $h\in U$, it holds that $|g(h)-l|<\varepsilon$. Since the sequence converges to $0$, there exists $n$ such that, for $m>n$ it holds that $|h_m|<\delta$. Thus, for $n>m$ it holds that $|g(h_m)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Now apply to $g(h)=(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$.